# RecyclerView returning position in getItemViewType method so it can be used in onCreateViewHolder

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am experimenting with `ReyclerView`, and I am trying to create one Adapter so I can use it in the whole application. Here is my Adapter:

```
public class RecyclerViewAdapter extends BaseRecyclerAdapter<ItemView, RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {

    public RecyclerViewAdapter(Context context) {
        super(context, new ArrayList<ItemView>());
    }

    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int position) {
        int viewType = getItem(position).getLayoutId();
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(viewType, parent, false);
        return getItem(position).getViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        getItem(position).bindViews();
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        return position;
    }
}
```

`BaseRecyclerAdapter` is a standard adapter that holds the items, and has the standard functions for adding, removing...

`ItemView` looks like this:

```
public abstract class ItemView {
    public abstract int getLayoutId();

    public abstract RecyclerView.ViewHolder getViewHolder(View view);

    public abstract void bindViews();
}
```

And now I can create Items extending ItemView, and I can use this adapter with different items.

The question is, is it safe to return the position in getItemViewType in this case? Or the recyclerView will create new views and will not recycle already created?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The question is, is it safe to return position in getItemViewType in this case? Or the recyclerView will create new views and will not recycle already created?

No, it is not "safe" to return the position from `getItemViewType()`, and your suspicion is correct: since the `View` type indicates whether an existing `View` can be recycled for a new data item which needs the same `View` type, an approach where each item has its unique `View` type will completely prevent recycling of  `View`s.

In the [documentation for `getItemViewType()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter#getitemviewtype) , it says

> Consider using id resources to uniquely identify item view types

Maybe this is a good idea for you: you already have this line in `onCreateViewHolder()`

> int viewType = getItem(position).getLayoutId();

So you can move it to `getItemViewType()`

```
@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    return getItem(position).getLayoutId();
}
```

and `onCreateViewHolder()` will look like this

```
@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewTypeResourceId) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(viewTypeResourceId, parent, false);
    return getItem(viewTypeResourceId).getViewHolder(view);
}
```

Note that I switched the parameter for `getItem()` from *position* to *viewTypeResourceId* because you only will have a *position* in `onBindViewHolder()`. There are some loose ends but I think your approach is still possible, you only have to provide a mapping of position to layout resource id and a mapping of layout resource id (aka view type) to a specific type of ViewHolder (And you can always get the `View` type for a given position by calling `getItemViewType()` )

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I already had `getItem(position).getLayoutId()` in `getItemViewType()`, but i don't have the position in `onCreateViewHolder()` and i can't get the viewHolder for the specific position. `getItem(viewTypeResourceId).getViewHolder(view)` would cause IndexOutOfBounds Exception. I will try to think different approach. I will accept this answer because it answers my concrete question.

Comment: @ElvedinSelimoski - your approach reminds me of [this blog post](https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/recyclerview-part-1-fundamentals-for-listview-experts/) because you have a `bindViews()` method but they have it ( `bindCrime()` ) in the ViewHolder whereas you have it in some other class. About the Exception: that's what I meant by "loose ends": I changed the code to indicate in which direction I would go (have `getItem()` not take positions but view types and have a separate mapping fom position to view type)

Comment: Yes, that was my next choice too. I created separate mapper which will be responsible just for mapping viewTypeIds with ViewHolders, and in bindViews() i will pass the holder to the ItemView.